# Understanding UIWindow Behavior in iOS App Delegates and Scene Delegates

Tags: swift, uikit

I have been working with UIWindow in the SceneDelegate and AppDelegate of my iOS app, and I'm puzzled by some aspects of UIWindow management. Here are the scenarios I'd like to understand better:

**Scenario 1: Custom Named UIWindow**

In SceneDelegate, I noticed that I can give any name to the UIWindow property, and it still works as expected. For instance:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  var someWindow: UIWindow?

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = getMainTabBar()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.someWindow = window
    return
  }
}
```

How does UIKit know which UIWindow to use when I name it differently, like "someWindow"? What's happening under the hood here? I can even create multiple variables with different names and UIKit will recognize them.

**Scenario 2: UIWindow Property and makeKeyAndVisible**

The guys below say that makeKeyAndVisible function adds window to the **windows** array. In the following code, I have two UIWindow properties in SceneDelegate, and I commented out the makeKeyAndVisible() call for the second window:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  var firstWindow: UIWindow?
  var secondWindow: UIWindow?

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    let firstWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    firstWindow.rootViewController = getMainTabBar()
    firstWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.firstWindow =  firstWindow

    let secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    secondWindow.windowScene = windowScene
    secondWindow.rootViewController = getSearchNC()
 //        secondWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.secondWindow = secondWindow
    return
  }
}
```

Even though I commented out the makeKeyAndVisible() call for the second window, it still gets added to the UIApplication.shared.windows array(I set a breakpoint before the return statement, and then inspect `po UIApplication.shared.windows`). It appears that setting the UIWindow property in SceneDelegate somehow adds it to the array. What's the explanation behind this behavior?

**Scenario 3: UIWindow Behavior with a Breakpoint**

If we assume from Scenario 2, that window gets added to array when we set it to delegate property, then this case even more confusing. I observed a peculiar behavior when I removed the UIWindow property from SceneDelegate like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = getMainTabBar()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return
  }
}
```

Surprisingly, if I set a breakpoint before the return statement, and then inspect `po UIApplication.shared.windows`, the window appears in the array, and the window is displayed if I continue execution. Why does this behavior occur only when I use a breakpoint? Without breakpoint it shows black screen as expected. What's the explanation behind it?

Console output for Scenario 2 and 3:
[image]

Comment: "It appears that setting the UIWindow property in SceneDelegate somehow adds it to the array." Maybe it happens in the setter of `UIWindow.windowScene`, when you assign windowScene to it. Just a guess. The other notable fact is, that `UIWindowSceneDelegate` is an "optional" protocol, with optional member `window`. So, that means, even you do not define the window property in your class `SceneDelegate `,  the code still compiles. If it works, well, I dunno. :) For any internal UIKit object using your delegate, the property `window` will be nil.

Comment: A further note, the `window` property may be set _implicitly_ from UIKit Storyboard, iff you have setup the entries in the Info.plist accordingly. If you have not already, you may download Apple's example project from this documentation page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/supporting_multiple_windows_on_ipad to see how this will be set up.

Comment: To your last question which causes you gripes, `UIApplication.shared.windows`  is **deprecated**, and it has been declared as this as this SceneDelegate stuff has been introduced. So, we need to be very careful when using it, even ifs it's just the debugger. Just imagine, what it might do, it might perform side effects, for example grabbing windows and collect them in `windows` in order to support some backward compatibility.

Comment: Yet another info: a UIWindowScene can have one or more UIWindows objects. There is a property for it `windows`. An application may have one or more "connected" scenes (visible, or being in background). Usually, we think of a scene as a "Window" on the screen.  You may check, how and when the property `windows` of the UIWindowScene object will be changed, when you are creating  a window with that scene.